# Unity foreach bugs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, foreach, game-physics, rigid-bodies

so I'm working on a dice game, at firs I thought it'll be easy but I just found 1 major "bug".
So this is my main script with the problem:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BoardController : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region VAR
    [SerializeField] private List<Transform> diceRestPositions = new List<Transform>();
    [SerializeField] private List<Transform> dices = new List<Transform>();
    [SerializeField] private Transform throwPosition;
    [SerializeField] private float throwRange;
    #endregion

    #region MONO
    private void Update()
    {
        LaunchDices();
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2))
        {
            ResetDicesPos();
        }
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        
    }
    #endregion

    #region CUSTOM

 
    private Vector3 GetRandomThrowPos()
    {
        return new Vector3(Random.Range(throwPosition.position.x- throwRange, throwPosition.position.x + throwRange), 1.2f, Random.Range(throwPosition.position.z - throwRange, throwPosition.position.z + throwRange));
    }

    private void ResetDicesPos()
    {
        StopDiceMovement();
        for (int i = 0; i < diceRestPositions.Count; i++)
        {
            dices[i].position = diceRestPositions[i].localPosition;
            dices[i].rotation = diceRestPositions[i].localRotation;
        }
    }
    private void StopDiceMovement()
    {
        foreach(Transform dice in dices)
        {
            if(dice.TryGetComponent<Rigidbody>(out Rigidbody rb))
            {
                rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
                dice.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
                rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
            }
        }
    }
    private void LaunchDices()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1)) 
        {
            StopDiceMovement();
            foreach (Transform dice in dices)
            {
                dice.position = GetRandomThrowPos();
                if(dice.TryGetComponent<DiceAddForce>(out DiceAddForce comp))
                {
                    comp.ApplyRandomForce();
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    #endregion    
}
```

So just to explain "diceRestPosition" is a list where dices are resting before getting launched.
"dices" is just a list with dice Transform.
"throwPosition" is just the middle point of throwingArea and "throwRange" defines the range.

So when i press "Alpha1" 5 dices are launching from a random position with rigidbody.AddForce and rigidbody.AddTorque so they are spinning.
And when I press "alpha2" every dice is returning to its position defined in "diceRestPosition".
But sometimes when I play with theses buttons some errors accure like:
-> when I'm double pressing 1 sometimes they just doubleJump like if so StopDiceMovement() isn't working
-> sometimes dices are launching from "diceRestPosition" and not random pos
-> and the last one is when I press 2 and dices are still moving they just stop but don't return to "diceRestPosition"

I'm quite new in programming and not really sure what to do but first i thought it was ressource error like foreach is too heavy and is skipped? But i  have only 5 dices and I don't think it's causing it.
I aslo saw that when dices are moving it's more probable to accure when they are still moving/rolling or when stopped are tilted.
If you read this I'm greatefull for your attention and ask you to help me resolve this strange error :)

Comment: For the record, there's no such noun as "dices". "Die" is the singular and "dice" is the plural. People will often use "dice" as a singular and all but the biggest pedants will let that go but you only have to be a bit of a pedant to get riled by the use of "dices" as a plural. At least treat the word like "sheep", i.e. both singular and plural.

Comment: And for the record, the bug is 99.9% in YOUR code not Unity!

Comment: One thing I can tell is: You are using a weird mix of going through `Rigidbody` and `Transform` of your dice ... as soon as any physics is involved you want to go **only through `Rigidbody`** .. for instance instead of assigning `dice.position`/`dice.rotation` you will rather want to go through `rb.position` and `rb.rotation`. => you will not want to repeat using `GetComponent` all the time so rather store them in a `List<Rigidbody>` right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm quite new in programming and not really sure what to do but first i thought it was ressource error like foreach is too heavy and is skipped?

No code will ever simply be skipped just because it is heavy. It will maybe lower the frame-rate or in extreme cases freeze your application - or if your device runs out of memory yes actually throw an exception - but it will never simply be skipped ;)

If you want to be sure whether things are being executed [Debug your code!](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)

---

One thing I can tell is: You are using a weird mix of going through `Rigidbody` and `Transform` of your dice.

As a rule of thumb: As soon as any physics is involved you want to go **only through `Rigidbody`**!

For instance instead of assigning

```
dice.position = wx;
dice.rotation = yz;
```

you will rather want to go through [`Rigidbody.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html) and [`Rigidbody.rotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-rotation.html).

---

Also some side notes

- It seems a bit odd that you also mix world `position` and `localPosition` in

  ```
  dices[i].position = diceRestPositions[i].localPosition;
  dices[i].rotation = diceRestPositions[i].localRotation;
  ```

  you will probably rather want to stick to either use the local space or the global space for both.
- You will also not want to repeatedly using `GetComponent` all the time so rather store them in a `List<Rigidbody>` right away.
- **OR** in fact even better than having two independent lists and just hoping they will have the same size always I would even have a custom wrapper type like e.g.

  ```
  [Serializable]
  private class DiceSetup
  {
      public Rigidbody Dice;
      public Transform RestPosition;
  }

  [SerializeField] private List<DiceSetup> dices = new();
  ```

  and then stick to a `foreach` everywhere

Comment: Thanks, I tested your idea and it works. I wasn't just aware that Rigidbody got his own Position and Rotation. Now it works perfectly and I also fixed the problem with TryGetComponent and put on Dice class some variables:

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how Unity handles Key (board) "repeat counts", but if you're not "locking" or otherwise skipping / handling "busy" code, you may be having re-entrancy issues if you're getting keys faster than you can handle them. The usual way to confirm "expected" and unexpected behaviour, is to add the appropriate Debug statements. Break points aren't that "friendly" in event handlers.

So, besides a "lock" (C# keyword) around your code, you can also set, unset (try finally) and test a busy flag to avoid re-entrancy.

Comment: (Most of) the Unity API is single threaded. [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) `is called once a frame`. Within one frame [`Input.GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) can only be `true` in case within that frame the key went down or `false` if not .. there will be no two `Update` iterations within a single frame and no two different states of the `Input` class within a single frame -> OPs methods will always be executed linear and synchronous